# Storing access tokens or keys in redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I am new using Redux store and state management. I wanted to know if it is safe to store access_tokens or identity tokens inside your redux store so you can grab it whenever you want to or there is a better place for these tokens for single page applications.

Comment: it's not safe to store the access token in the local storage, you have to store it encrypted using for example [iron-session](https://github.com/vvo/iron-session)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as long as you use a [subscriber or middleware](https://michaelwashburnjr.com/2017/11/21/best-way-to-store-tokens-redux/)

I recommend checking out [this tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-persisting-the-state-to-the-local-storage) by Dan Abramov to get an idea of how to do this correctly.